# Move Folder with parent path Windows

Tags: windows, cmd, server, move, directory

Does somebody know a way to move a folder from one path to another with the "parent" folder ?

For example, all these folders:
[image: Parent]

Contain a folder named "Win" see below:
[image]

i want to copy the folder "Win" with the parent folder ( the numbers ) and move it to a new location example -> "C:\Storage\migration"

there are over 200 folders, so right now i am manually creating a folder named these numbers and copy & pasting the Win folder into it, it is very time consuming and not a very good long term solution :(

Maybe something could be done with a BAT. script or like ?

Comment: I'd combine `for /F` [loop command](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)  against the results of `dir /b /ad "d:\BaswareRay\OES"` with `copy` or [Robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html). Feel free to [edit] your question, add record attained, ask more about...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
for /d %%a in ("d:\BaswareRay\OES\*") do (
    xcopy "%%~fa\win\*" "c:\storage\migration\%%~nxa\win\" /y /s /e
    echo rmdir /s /q "%%~fa\win"
)
```

For each folder under the indicated source, recursively copy its contents to the target folder and remove the source folder.

For each folder, the `for` command replaceable parameter `%%a` will hold a reference to the folder being processed. Using this reference, `%%~fa` will return the full path of the folder and `%%~nxa` the name and extension of the folder.

The deletion of source folder is only echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` that precedes the `rmdir` command

Comment: This is Perfect, however the source folder should not be removed or modified in any way, i practically only need to copy from source folder to new location :) i believe i can just remove the "Echo rmdir etc.." ?

Comment: @MikeJohansen, yes, remove the `echo rmdir ...` line and source folder will not be modified. I included it because of the `move` in your question.

Comment: Just a quick question, if i wanted to copy for example the txt file only:
"for /d %%a in ("C:\Folder\*") do (
    xcopy "%%~fa\*.txt" "D:\Win folders migration\%%~nxa\" /y /s /e
) " can i make that not go into sub directories ?

Comment: @MikeJohansen, the `/s` switch in `xcopy` command is what selects recursive copy. Remove it.